# How to integrate rest api test using soapui with selenium using junit framework

Tags: rest, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, soapui

I want to integrate selenium-webdriver framework written using junit with soapui rest api test suites, is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a soapui project with test cases done for rest api? How are you currently running the junit tests? such as  from any IDE or command line? When you say selenium webdriver, I believe that they are pure UI automation, right? Is there any relation between UI tests and rest tests ?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html

Comment: @Rao - Yes there is a relation between UI tests and rest test. I recently started working on soapui and I have all those test cases in place. I am running my junit tests from IDE(Eclipse)

Comment: @SiKing Thanks for the link, Yes I have seen this, this is for integrating wsdl project (i.e. SOAP project) with selenium. My requirement is to integrate REST with Selenium

Comment: When you say there is relation, can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Rao whatever UI test is there I have covered it under selenium, I want to cover all the backend (i.e. REST API) from SOAPUI, after some api call I want to check UI for the update so that I can handle end to end testing from selenium reducing manual intervention

Comment: @user3736730, thank you for the info, please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is how you need to change your tests, so that, you will be able to run both kinds of tests together from *within SoapUI* i.e.,`rest  and ui`.

I am not sure, if you already happened to create a soapui project. If not, create the project, import your `.wadl or swagger definition` of **REST API**.

Then create test suite, and test cases as required.

Now the test case should be having the steps as defined:

- **Rest Request Step**(one or multiple steps) : this contains all your rest api calls
- **Groovy Script** : Whatever test code that you have in your junit test, needs to come here. Groovy should be able to run most of your java code. But, if you are familiar, you can add groovy code itself. So, that it will be able to do exactly the same as you run it from your eclipse IDE.

Bringing your test steps into soapui test case will also have an added advantage that you can even share the data (in the form of variables ) across rest and UI as well.

You can even execute the tests using SoapUI's commandline utility testrunner.bat/.sh of SOAPUI_HOME/bin directory.

It is also possible to define application url / credentials in the form of Project / test suite / test case level properties (as applicable to the tests) and use [Property Expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html). This even helps to run the tests against different servers such as dev, qa etc.,

I understand that you wanted to junit to execute the tests, but if you wanted to purely junit, then there is no need / get benefit using SoapUI. Instead of SoapUI, you can use different library, such as [groovy wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) to make rest calls in junit itself .

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, this really helps. As I have both SoapUI and selenium test suites in place, I just wanted to integrate both as moving the whole junit framework under groovy is time consuming and I don't want to add extra time in that. Anyway I ll go through groovy-wslite. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Appreciate if you accept it as answer if you think that helps.